# jQuery animate for different size of device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I do have the following JQuery code:

```
$("#keypad-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($("#numbers").hasClass("toggled")) {
        $("#numbers").animate({
            "height": "68%"
        }, function() {
            $("#innernumpad").hide();
        }).removeClass("toggled");
    } else {
        $("#numbers").animate({
            "height": "51%"
        }).addClass("toggled");
        $("#innernumpad").show();
    }
});
```

It's function is to slide the keypad from the bottom of the screen to the top. I've set it to slide up to 51% of the div height, so the original height of the div will be 68%. This height looks perfect on a desktop screen. I tried this values on different device heights, the div's height won't display properly. So, how do we set the height of sliding for different device? By the use of media queries? How do we convert this part of the code so that it can support different devices?

The jsfiddle looks like this:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/obnr1akj/)

Comment: Maybe a fiddle help us to know how it works. I think that you need to make some height calculations with viewport base height.

Comment: I've edited the question sir.

Comment: put your all div inside this<div class="container">